# fullcalendarの定期イベントdowの一部上書き（非表示）について。

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

[fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/)のイベントについて行き詰っており質問です。

#### 実現したいこと

1. 国民の休日をgoogleから取得
2. スタッフの毎週の出勤日をカレンダーに表示[]（eventSourcesにdowで実装）←ここまでは実装できています。
3. **会社の公休日にスタッフの出勤日を表示しないようにしたい。（←ここで行き詰ってます。）**

#### fullcalendar 現状のコード

```
  <script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src='js/fullcalendar.js'></script>
  <script src='js/ja.js'></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    firstDay: 1,
    timeFormat: 'H:mm',
    axisFormat: 'H:mm',
  eventSources:[
    {
      url: 'data/json1.php',//ここでGoogleの休日を取得してます。
      dataType: 'json',
    },
    {
      url: 'data/json2.php',//※１
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        id: "1",
        id2: "100",
      },
    },
  ]
  });
});
</script>
```

※１の部分

```
    一部省略（POSTでIDを参考に）
  $list = array();
  $i=0;
    foreach ($app->getValues()->staff_all as $staff) {
    $list[$i]['title']="出勤日";
    $list[$i]['color']="blue";
    $list[$i]['start']=$staff->in_time;//出勤時間
    $list[$i]['end']=$staff->out_time;//終わり時間
    $list[$i]['dow']="[".$staff->in_yobi."]";//毎週の曜日指定
    $i++;
  }
  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode($list);
```

上記のコードで毎週の予定は取れているのですが、
それに合わせて、会社の公休日は表示されないようにしたいのですが、
どんなコードを追記すればよいのかわからず行き詰っております。
英語が得意ではなく、fullcalendar を眺めているのですが、解決方法が見つからず
ご教授頂ければ幸いです。

環境
php 5.6
mysql 5.6
fullcalendar-3.7.0

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/101923

Answer (score 0):

予定をDBから抽出する時に、公休日を除外するSQLにすればいいのではないでしょうか？？
SQLは変更不可？

あとは、
fullcalendarのイベント描画のタイミングでカレンダーに表示しないようにすることは可能だと思います。
JSONに公休日の情報も含めて判別できるようにする

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    if (event.公休日判別フラグ == true) {
        return false; // イベント描画を抜ける
    }
},
```